# How to increase global maxfiles ulimit on OSX 13.1 Ventura

Tags: macos, launchd, ventura

This is an old problem, but again, none of the old solutions work anymore.

Default ulimit is far too low and I need to increase it to basically unlimited (like let's say a million).

And I need to increase it globally. Not just in the shell, so `.zshrc`-based solutions won't work; notably they won't apply to docker.

Increasing it in launchctl doesn't seem to persist it (and does it even do anything?)

(and yes, I now there's a lot of existing answers to this - but they only work on older OSX; I don't know if there's any "close as no longer working" function)

Comment: There's no 'close as no longer working' button because older macOS versions are still used, so the solutions are still relevant.

Answer (score 2):

> Increasing it in launchctl doesn't seem to persist it (and does it even do anything?)

If you need the `ulimit` modification to a specific launch daemon/agent, then you could try adding this to your `.plist` file (which works for me on Ventura)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>

...

  <key>HardResourceLimits</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NumberOfFiles</key>
    <integer>64000</integer>
  </dict>
  <key>SoftResourceLimits</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NumberOfFiles</key>
    <integer>64000</integer>
  </dict>

...

</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are working steps. It requires 4 restarts. Old methods do not work:

- boot into recovery mode - shut down the computer, press power button and keep holding it until Options appear, select Options, Continue
- open Terminal from menu and run: `csrutil clear`
- restart and return to the recovery mode like before
- open Terminal from menu and run: `csrutil disable`
- restart again (nto normal mode
- create `/Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist`, [following insturctions from this post](https://www.macobserver.com/tips/deep-dive/evade-macos-many-open-files-error-pushing-limits/) (contents also copied below)
- restart again, you finally have correct maxfiles limit globally

Here's what should be in `limit.maxfiles.plist`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
 "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0"> 
 <dict>
 <key>Label</key>
 <string>limit.maxfiles</string>
 <key>ProgramArguments</key>
 <array>
 <string>launchctl</string>
 <string>limit</string>
 <string>maxfiles</string>
 <string>64000</string>
 <string>524288</string>
 </array>
 <key>RunAtLoad</key>
 <true/>
 <key>ServiceIPC</key>
 <false/>
 </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Interestingly, the default value for `sysctl kern.maxfiles` in Ventura is 245760, and maxfilesperproc is 122880. Number of processes is 5333. That's up from the 256 files and 709 processes in Sierra, claimed by your linked article.

Comment: Shouldn't you enable `csrutil enable` again after creating the file?

Comment: This no longer works in Ventura 13.4.1 :(. `sysctl kern.maxfiles` still show 65535 :(