# macOS Ventura "Too many open files"

Tags: macos, finder, smb, ventura, docker

I am trying to run several Docker containers on my new M2 Mac Mini, but I keep running into issues passing my SMB network drive through to the containers. I am able to add the path to the container without issue, but shortly after starting the container, I begin to experience issues. Looking in terminal on my Mac, I see this error: `fts_read: Too many open files`. I have tried everything under the sun to resolve this issue, including following several guides (most recently [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/453050/how-to-increase-global-maxfiles-ulimit-on-osx-13-1-ventura)), but it still did not work.

Running `launchctl limit maxfiles` I receive this: `maxfiles    524288         524288`

I am at my wits end with this as this has been an issue for me for several weeks now. It seems like Apple may have changed how to raise the limit in Ventura based on the above post, but no matter what method I use, I am running into the same issue.