# Can't change system limit with launchctl anymore

Tags: macos, launchd, plist

I have a launchctl service

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>limit.maxfiles</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>launchctl</string>
            <string>limit</string>
            <string>maxfiles</string>
            <string>524288</string>
            <string>524288</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>ServiceIPC</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

It works on MacOS before Ventura. On Ventura when I load the service with launchctl it prompts me `Load failed: 109: Invalid property list`.

What's wrong here?

Comment: [This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/453050/how-to-increase-global-maxfiles-ulimit-on-osx-13-1-ventura) here on AskDifferent has no accepted answers, but may provide a solution.