# How to increase global max opened files limit on OSX 13.5 Ventura

Tags: macos, launchd, ventura

I already had configured max opened files limit and it worked fine until I updated to Ventura 13.5. The limit is reset to default value now.

I tried to follow answer from this question: [How to increase global maxfiles ulimit on OSX 13.1 Ventura](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/453050/how-to-increase-global-maxfiles-ulimit-on-osx-13-1-ventura?newreg=44fe471004094ccdb3ba51c1c3f9f84a)

It worked until I enabled System Integrity Protection back via `csrutil enable`. When I enabled it back, the limit was reset to default value again. And I can't just disable System Integrity Protection because of company policy.

Is there a fix or a workaround for this? Or is it just a bug and we have to wait for next version or rollback to previous?

Answer (score 4):

Apple has acknowledged that this is a bug and provided a workaround on their Developer forum article ["No Longer Able to Increase Maxfile Limits MacOS Recent Versions"](https://developer.apple.com/forums//thread/735798?answerId=762208022#762208022)

For me, the following command worked:

```
sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 128000 524288
```

After that, I set `ulimit` like where `softlimit` is equal to `hardlimit` of `maxfiles`.

```
ulimit -n 524288 10485760
```

To persist the above change follow the GitHub Gist post ["How to Change Open Files Limit on OS X and macOS"](https://gist.github.com/tombigel/d503800a282fcadbee14b537735d202c)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Here is what I did.

Context:

- launchctl limit maxfiles --> maxfiles 256 unlimited

256 is by far not enough for my application

Actions:

- more /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist

to examine the /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist file, there the limits were 20000 20000

- reboot with +R (recovery mode)
- launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist

to modify permanently the 2 limits

- reboot normally

At that point, my problem was solved. But

- I did not re-enable crsutil (I'll try when I'll have made up for the time lost on this Apple bug, but as I am the sole user of this machine and that type of modification can only be done in recovery mode, I feel quite safe to stay this way...)
- there is a curious discrepancy:

ulimit -> unlimited

ulimit -Sn 20000

ulimit -Hn 20000

I hope this can help.

Comment: Unfortunately disabling System Integrity Protection indefinitely is not a viable solution for most users. Does anyone have an answer that does not involve permanently disabling SIP?

Comment: Thank you for response, but yes, unfortunately I can't keep SIP turned off

Comment: Disabling SIP is not an option. Did anyone report this issue on apple forum? Everything was working just fine till 13.5 upgrade. Tried 13.5.1 upgrade too, it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I brought this to the Apple forum and the [answer](https://developer.apple.com/forums//thread/735798?answerId=762208022#762208022) I received there helped me to add a fix. Since I knew what process was opening the high volume of files I went with the wrapper approach and added the following bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash

ulimit -n 2000000
exec <process that is opening a large number of files>
```

Running this bash file instead of the process directly allowed me to run a Vite server which opens a large number of files despite not being able to change the global maxfile limits on my Mac on the newest OS.

Comment: For me this just prints `line 3: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted` and does not allow to call ulimit.